# Creating false entries with composite foreign key

Tags: foreign-keys, key, foreign-key-relationship, composite-key

I'm using a MySQL database. I have two tables, Table 1 and Table 2. There is a composite primary key in Table 1. There is a composite foreign key in Table 2 that references the Composite PK in Table 1.

The problem I have is illustrated below:

Table 1
|------------PK-----------|
menuid   | categoryid  | categoryname
1    |1     |myCategoryName1
1    |2     |myCategoryName2
2    |1     |myCategoryName3
2    |2     |myCategoryName4
2    |3     |myCategoryName5

I can create an entry in Table 2 that is referencing a false entry in Table 1:

Table 2
|------------FK-----------| |----PK----|
menuid  | categoryid  | postid |post name
1    |3     |1     |myPostName

Now, it's not a big problem since I can insert valid values into the database. However, this seems like a relational error in the database and I would like to have a clean, correctly-functioning DB. Is there a way to correct this minor problem?

**UPDATE:** I was using phpMyAdmin to implement my database and apparently there is no way of implementing composite foreign keys in phpMyAdmin. I was able to look at my incorrectly-implemented foreign key via

`SHOW CREATE TABLE Table2`

where `Table2` is the name of my second table with the composite foreign key.

Then I correctly added composite foreign key manually via

`ALTER TABLE Table2 ADD CONSTRAINT my_fk_constraint

FOREIGN KEY (menuid, categoryid)

REFERENCES Table1(menuid, categoryid)`

where `my_fk_constraint` is the name of the constraint being added.

**Note:** Manually adding foreign key constraints this way does not allow you to use a drop-down menu when inserting new entries (nor referring to the corrresponding table by clicking on the FK columns), as you would normally be able to in phpMyAdmin.

Thanks `pst` and `thedayofcondor`, you are both correct because I'm a small-dicked freak using phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Make sure a proper relation-aware backing is being used (i.e. InnoDB, but not MyISAM). Also, have these FK's been defined via DML (or are they just logical)? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct: no, prevent: yes!

This should not happen if you set your constraints properly:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Comment: I was using phpMyAdmin and it turns out I was incorrectly implementing the foreign key constraint (as far as I know, phpMyAdmin cannot implement composite foreign keys). I manually added the composite foreign key constraint using DML, so thanks to you and pst as well for being correct.